# Fragment over another fragment within ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment, swipe, overlap

Hello I'm trying to build a ViewPager with 3 Fragments. One of this fragment have another fragment that overlap and I want implement swiping up and down to show and hide the fragment.

Here there is a image that explain my question

[image: ViewPager System]

In the ViewPager I can slide right  and left . When I'm in the second fragment I want to be able to swipe up and down to show/hide the fourth fragment.

Hope I was clear. I was inspired to Snapchat app layout.

Thank you for help.

Comment: Remove "SOLVED" from your title and post the solution you found as a proper **answer**. You can even accept it, if you like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several research, I've found a library that make implementation of sliding panels very easy.

It's the **Umano Android Panel**

[Umano Android Panel repository](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel)

Answer (score 0):

You can't using the sdk's viewpager.

There are tons of other ways doing it.

Here is one way of accomplishing the task!

https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-DirectionalViewPager/

Comment: i'm not sure if AndroidDirectionalViewPAger is the right way. Because using ViewPager i cant overlap a fragment. i need to overlap fragment over another. My fourth fragment must be translucent and overlap the second fragment..Maybe the fourth fragment can be thought as  vertical drag pane?